# Priority Queue error when finding greatest numeric palindrome that is product of two numbers in a given range

Tags: python, priority-queue, palindrome

I am trying to find to the largest numeric palindrome that is a product of two numbers in a given range. First, I've written a simple function to check if the number is indeed a palindrome:

```
import math

def check_palindrome(n):
    if n == 0: //O is a palindrome
        return True
    else:
        check = [0]
        i = 1              //Find the power of the number
        while (n/i) >= 10:
            i = i*10
        m = n
        j = 0
        while i >= 1:         //Add each digit to a list
            j = math.floor(m/i)
            check.append(j)
            m = m-(j*i)
            i = i/10
        length = len(check)
        if length == 1:      //One digit number is always a palindrome
            return True
        else:
            i = 1       //Check if list is a palindrome
            while i <= length/2:
                if check[i] != check[-i]:
                    return False
                i += 1
            return True
```

Next, I've implemented a priority queue and declared a class that contains a factor, the current number in the given range that is being multiplied by that factor, and functions for returning the value of this product and moving to the next lowest number.

```
import heapq

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, priority, x):
        heapq.heappush(self.items, (-priority, x))

    def pop(self):
        _, x = heapq.heappop(self.items)
        return x

    def empty(self):
        return not self.items

class Products:
    def __init__(self, factor, current):
        self.f = factor
        self.c = current

    def value(self):
        return self.f*self.c

    def move(self):
        self.c -= 1
```

Finally, the main function, which fills the priority queue with Product classes containing each factor between min and max and initially set to multiply by itself, given priority by the magnitude of its product, then pops the Product with the highest product and checks if it is a palindrome and if not requeues it with the number the factor is being multiplied by set one lower and continues to check the next highest Product until it finds a palindrome.

```
def max_palindrome(maximum, minimum):
    q = PriorityQueue()
    i = maximum
    while i >= minimum:
        p = Products(i, i)
        q.push(p.value(), p)
        i -= 1
    check = False
    while not check:
        p = q.pop()
        check = check_palindrome(p.value())
        if not check and p.c > minimum:
            p.move()
            q.push(p.value(), p)
    return p.value()
```

My problem is that max_palindrome() returns the correct answer up to (329,0), but range with a maximum of 330 or greater returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    max_palindrome(330,0)
  File "C:\Users\Alec Collins\Documents\Euler\problem 4.py", line 67, in max_palindrome
    p = q.pop()
  File "C:\Users\Alec Collins\Documents\Euler\problem 4.py", line 52, in pop
    _, x = heapq.heappop(self.items)
TypeError: unorderable types: Products() < Products().
```

Clearly something is up with the priority queue so the pop is not working but I have no idea what. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when two items have the same value?

Comment: I'm getting `NameError: name 'l' is not defined` on the `if l == 1:` line in your `check_palindrome` function. Is this exactly the code that you're running?

Comment: @Kevin oops it should be length == 1

Comment: @user2357112 for ranges with a difference of less than 8 it returns 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    max_palindrome(99,92)
  File "C:\Users\Alec Collins\Documents\Euler\problem 4.py", line 67, in max_palindrome
    p = q.pop()
  File "C:\Users\Alec Collins\Documents\Euler\problem 4.py", line 52, in pop
    _, x = heapq.heappop(self.items)
IndexError: index out of range'

Answer (score 0):

When a heap has two items with the same priority*, it compares their values using the "less than" operator to determine their comparative order. But your `Products` class doesn't implement that operator.

Try implementing `__lt__` for your class.

```
class Products:
    def __init__(self, factor, current):
        self.f = factor
        self.c = current

    def value(self):
        return self.f*self.c

    def move(self):
        self.c -= 1

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value() < other.value()
```

(*this is something of a simplification; the heap algorithm does not have a native conception of "priority". But the outcome is the same; when you store two-element tuples in a heap, the second elements of each tuple are only compared when the first elements are equal, because that's how tuple comparison always works in Python.)